# Can someone give a concrete example of exploitation in the context of Exploratory Data Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, exploratory-data-analysis

This [post](https://nthu-datalab.github.io/ml/labs/02_EDA_PCA/02_EDA_PCA.html#Exploratory-Data-Analysis) says Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) consists of 2 steps exploration and exploitation.

I know a little about [exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_exploration) which uses some techniques such as data visualization to understand what is in a dataset and the characteristics of the data.

In this context, what is exploitation? Can someone give a concrete example of exploitation?

Comment: Have you considered searching our site for [EDA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+EDA+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10)?  Among the posts I have written about EDA you can find many that illustrate this iteration, such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/114620/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919, and even the very artificial circumstances at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10520/919.

Answer (score 0):

> In this context, what is exploitation? Can someone give a concrete
>   example of exploitation?

from the article:

> Then, in the exploitation step, you use the identified characteristics to figure out the next things to explore. You then repeat the above two steps until you are satisfied with what you have learned from the data

and the answer is also in the data, they first do a Pairwise Join Distributions and then later they are doing a correlation matrix. The exploitation step in this article explains, that you have to go deeper after you start during exploration.