# Does the lack of a basic effect preclude more complex post-hoc analyses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, effect-size

I (Psychology PhD student) have a large dataset consisting of a variety of numerical variables that I predicted may be related to one another. I have performed some basic statistical analyses (a factorial ANOVA or two) and I have found none of the hypothesized effects. Is it now worth performing more complex analyses post-hoc (e.g. a moderated regression or something along those lines), or does the fact I have not found even a basic effect preclude me from doing that?

In other words, if a basic statistical test hasn't produced any relevant statistically significant effects, is it justifiable to then ask the same question using a more complex statistical test? Or is that just fishing for some kind of esoteric weak effect to report? I will be presenting this research at a conference, so I'm trying to pre-empt any questions of "why didn't you do this or that more complex test?". Statistics isn't my strongest asset, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing should preclude you from exploring your data as much as you like. The problem is if you do this long enough, you're guaranteed to find a "significant" result.  "If you torture the data long enough, it will confess."  To avoid potentially devastating criticism, many people initially select a fair-sized random subset of their data and use that for exploration.  Then you have more data in reserve to verify anything you think you saw in this process.  To see how common this is, search our site for references to [test and training](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+train*).

Comment: @whuber That makes sense, thank you. I suppose what I'm also wondering, more simply, is whether there is anything more complex analyses could tell me that hasn't already been answered by a simple analysis firmly reporting "nothing to see here"?Although I suppose that depends on the analyses in question!

Comment: Yes.  It depends on the data, on what you're looking for, the extent to which the data might conform to theoretical predictions, and (to be frank) your skill with exploring and analyzing data.  Long ago we conducted a tiny experiment in this regard: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10363.  Seven people contributed analyses of the same (artificial) dataset.  Results were all over the place, ranging from essentially useless and misleading results to near-perfect (but still not exact!) fits.