# Logistic regression before decision tree model

Tags: regression, logistic, cart

I am trying to run several decision tree models (CHAID, C&RT, QUEST), but I have learned that several researchers have applied logistic regression model first in order to select risk factors. So, once they have significantly factors they used them to perform a decision tree.

It is the best way to do that? Do I really need to do this before a decision tree? If so, what are the advantages?

Comment: Do you have any references? It sounds a bit odd to use logistic regression to select features for decision tree.

Comment: See whether the material on CHAID at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/what-skills-are-required-to-perform-large-scale-statistical-analyses is helpful.

Comment: Zhurbarb, this is the reference that talks about doing Logistic regression before decision tree model:

http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6963/14/382

Answer (score 1):

Doing feature selection based on statistical significance is [a bad idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451480/feature-selection-for-logistic-regression/451576#451576).

There are no real advantages to doing this.  With enough data, all effects will be significant, so you would end up selecting all the variables.  Not only that, but the p values doesn't tell you anything about the size of the effect so you might end up selecting features which effect the outcome in a negligible way.

There is no need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some are thinking it as a way to do variable selection via automated stepwise or other methods, but I think it might hide some problems related to data minining results quality.

Why not do first independently all models and do some quality checking via ROC-curves or such?

It could also be proper to do ensembling, such as averaging probability estimates from the various models.

Comment: I'd be interested in an expanded version of this answer.

Comment: "It could also be proper to do ensembling, such as averaging probability estimates from the various models." -- this is effectively what a random forest does.