# Logit Regression and F-test: Can I apply the f statistic when variables are non-normal and the output is binary?

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, scikit-learn, f-test, regression-strategies

I want to do a univariate analysis on a set of variables to see which predict a binary outcome. I want to discard some of them before performing logistic regression.

I am trying to understand if I can rely on the f-test outputs (as provided by `f_classif` in `sklearn`) when my variables are non-normal and the outcome is binary.

I understand that in a ols regression problem this f-test compares the variance of the residuals between a model with intercept only and the variance of a model with the variable included. So, I would think the original distribution of the dependent variables is not problematic. Now, in logistic regression I would think it is the same, but I can't find any background related to this `f_classif` for binary outcomes and I don't understand what residuals are compared.

My apologies in advance if this question is basic.

Comment: Univariate screeining is not considered a good strategy, see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451480/feature-selection-for-logistic-regression  and search this site!

Comment: These f_test and f_classif  as they are implemented in python are not a univariate analysis.

Comment: Then it seems the Q needs an answerer knowing sklearn, so I added that tag!