# Hypothesis testing on subsamples and cross validation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, sampling, bootstrap, resampling

When working on very large datasets, identifying effects rests more on quantification than significance and many questions/answers give insight on what to do regarding large samples like [this (very good) answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7933/208698).

Although deciding if an effect is quantitatively interesting can be rather easily done for some tests (*e.g* mean difference and such), I can't say the same for others, so I'm trying to go for a *sampling* approach, but have little experience as to what this implies for analysis.

I'm trying to compare the (near identical) distributions of 2 samples, both of which have large sample sizes (~20 000 each). 
I'm pretty sure that the 2 samples are from an equal distribution, but using a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test will almost systematically return  near-zero p-values with this sample size, so I want to sub-sample each of these 2 initial samples and compare the subs (which I make ~1000 values). 
Doing this a few times gave me the expected results -- no significant difference between the 2 -- most of the time (~92%).

How do I go about rigorously doing and explaining this? Saying "The test was done on subsamples *n* times and came out as negative *x*% of the time" seems wrong. Also, when cross-validating/bootstrapping something, there are bound to be repeated tests so do I need to do p-value adjustments on these?

Comment: This approach seems strange to me. Maybe estimate the treatment effect, and present a confidence interval? Then ask yourself if any of the values within that CI have any **practical** significance in your application area?

Answer (score 1):

Probably just stating the obvious here, but if the two samples are actual from the same distribution, then it shouldn't matter how large your sample size is. Your p-values will mostly come back larger than 0.05.

```
data1 <- rnorm(20000, 0, 5)
data2 <- rnorm(20000, 0, 5)

ks.test(data1, data2)
```

Even a difference in means of say 0.1 isn't usually going to be picked up with 20,000 samples. This returns mostly p-values larger than 0.05.

```
data1 <- rnorm(20000, 0, 5)
data2 <- rnorm(20000, 0.1, 5)

ks.test(data1, data2)
```

On the other hand, if you take small enough samples from your samples, even if your two samples are from distinctly different distributions, your p-values will come back mostly positive.

```
data1 <- rnorm(40, 0, 5)
data2 <- rnorm(40, 0, 4)

ks.test(data1, data2)
```

Maybe your problem is better suited for some approach other than null hypothesis testing and p-values if you just want to establish that the distributions are similar enough for your purposes but not identical.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure whether the methods I am exploring in this answer is common or not. But I will give it a try and share what I think.

I believe your problem can be broken into two parts:

a) Explaining things using only the p-values:

Boxplot of the p-values can be shown to show the distribution of p-values. You can also plot the frequency distribution, etc.

b) Reporting something over how many times the p-value was significant.

You can measure how many times the p-value was significant, for ex- less than 0.05. This random variable will follow a binomial distribution. You can estimate the parameters of this distribution and also compute some descriptive statistics from the sample over which this distribution has been estimated.