# Determine if there is a difference between two large vectors of different sizes of non-normal quantiative data in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two vectors that are of unequal sizes. They contain quantitative data that does not form a normal distribution. I would like to see whether or not they are statistically different. Is there a good program to use in R to achieve this?

I am thinking I should not use t-test (as that assumes normality) or Wilcoxon (as that uses pair groups of equal sizes).

Comment: Can you say more about the variables you're observing? Are they discrete, for example? Bounded? How are they obtained? Also, there are many ways that distributions can differ; what kinds of difference are you interested in?

Comment: Also, what are the sample sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tests named after Wilcoxon.

The one you mention is the *signed rank test*, but there's also the *rank sum test*, which might well be suitable for your problem. It's sometimes called the [Mann-Whitney test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test).

It can be used to test for a location shift, or a scale shift, or more general alternatives, including stochastic dominance. For more general differences still, you might consider a two-sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test).

You might also consider a [permutation/randomization test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) (particularly if you're interested in a difference in means).

(In R, both wilcoxon tests can be obtained via `wilcox.test`, and the two Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests can be obtained via `ks.test`. Randomization tests are also very easy to carry out.)

Comment: I think still have the problem described here [Are large data sets inappropriate for hypothesis testing?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/are-large-data-sets-inappropriate-for-hypothesis-testing)