# How to test amount of differences in T-test in R for large samples?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test

We have good discussions on [hypothesis testing in large data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/are-large-data-sets-inappropriate-for-hypothesis-testing): With large amount of data, even tinny difference between two samples can be detected, and we are almost certain to reject NULL hypothesis.

Effect size is one "fix", but I am interested in other fix, where, in addition to say they are different, but say how much the difference are.

I not know how to do it in R. Let us assume we are doing two sample T test, how can I say I want to test if the means are different by say certain amount say $0.1$ ?

The following code is test if two means are equal. How to modify it to test if two means are difference by $0.1$?

```
sample1=rnorm(1e5)
sample2=rnorm(1e5)
t.test(sample1,sample2)


    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  sample1 and sample2
t = -0.5542, df = 2e+05, p-value = 0.5794
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.01124444  0.00628720
sample estimates:
    mean of x     mean of y 
-0.0002658978  0.0022127222
```

Edit:

I was trying to ask if the amount difference on mean of two samples within range of $-0.1$ to $0.1$, not exactly to equal $0.1$.

Reading Peter Flom 's comment, modifying T test will not meet my needs?

Comment: In a regular two sample t-test the null is "the two means are equal".  In a test of equivalence, the null is "the two means are different by at least XXX".  I think you want something else, namely null is "the two means are withing XXX"

Answer (score 2):

R code questions are actually off-topic here but it is:

```
t.test(sample1, sample2, alternative = "two.sided", mu = 0.1)
```

I think the question should stay here, however, because it raises a statistical question. My view is that looking for an effect larger than a certain amount makes a lot of sense, but it can be hard to choose an amount.

Comment: Thanks, I thought to ask it to stack overflow.. but as you said, it raises a statistical question.

Comment: No, it's not a stack overflow question either - because it's not really about programming.  It's an interesting statistics question along with a very basic R question.

Comment: two.sided not two-sided.  But I'm not sure this is right, I think the OP really wants the null hypothesis is mu is between -0.1 and 0.1, and alternative is that abs(mu) > 0.1 (not mu = 0.1).?

Comment: Thanks for the syntax fix but I think what I had does test abs(mu) > 0.1.  Exactly 0.1 doesn't make sense.  Unless I am missing something (which certainly could be the case).  Are you suggesting OP wants a test of equivalence?

Comment: @PeterFlom sorry I was trying to ask within range of -0.1 to 0.1, not exactly to equal 0.1

Comment: What is -0.1 to 0.1? Confidence interval?

Comment: Now you've got me confused.  A test of equivalence is inherently quite different from a (regular) t test. I don't think a TofE is a solution to the big data issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your test has the null hypothesis that difference = 0.1 and "alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0.1" (from the output).  So the small p-value it returns just means there is evidence against the difference in means being exactly 0.1.

Comment: I think @hxd1011 needs to clarify his question

Answer (score 2):

There is not a usual way to use a t-test to test if the absolute difference is larger than 0.1, or even to test if the difference lies within a given range.

However, your goal of assessing how large the difference is can be achieved by using the confidence interval. It's already in your results, since R and most statistical packages produce a confidence interval when told to perform a t-test:

```
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.01124444  0.00628720
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach.  Fuzzy null hypotheses are tricky in the frequentist paradigm, and more attention to the effect size rather than a sharp hypothesis test is the best and simplest thing to explain and encourage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to attempt to answer the R portion of this question, but I wanted to comment on this: "*Effect size is one "fix", but I am interested in other fix, where, in addition to say they are different, but say **how much the difference are**.*"

The purpose of effect size is to attach a measure of magnitude of effect, or difference, between the populations (or treatments).

If you are not familiar with effect sizes, I recommend you read:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/
and
http://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00002182.htm

> 'Effect size' is simply a way of quantifying the size of the difference between two groups.

As a statistical consultant, I always push for reporting of effect sizes to any statistical product.

An Edit:

I want to comment on this: "*I was trying to ask if the amount difference on mean of two samples within range of −0.1−0.1 to 0.10.1, not exactly to equal 0.10.1.*"

I think there needs to be some clarity on this. What exactly is -0.1 to 0.1? Is this a confidence interval? Acceptance region?

Comment: +1, I think may need your help to say it formally. What in my mind, is: we know they are different, but can we say they are different by $x$ amount?

Comment: No. That's the purpose of a confidence interval. You're 95% confident that the difference between Pop A and B is -0.1 to 0.1. Also, note that that's another big issue. If 0 is in your Conf Interval, then it's REALLY difficult to accept that there is a difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract or add 0.1 to one of the datasets.

Comment: thanks, my question was not clear. could you take a look at my edit?